# how can you pass a text value to adobe creative sdk image component?

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I am building an Android app and am using the Adobe Creative SDK.

I want to know if it is possible to pass a text value to the SDK's Image Editor UI component to be overlaid on the image.

Comment: Want to make a watermark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to pass a string to the Creative SDK's Image Editor UI component from another part of your app.

The Image Editor does make it possible for your users to add text to their photo themselves using the Text tool:
[image]